# Kotlin store list in RecyclerView by SharedPrefernce

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, spinner

I m trying to store list which i get from spinner from modal class  store in `RecyclerView` shared preference  but i m only getting last item selected instead of multiple selection from spinner

```
  spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {

                val data_  = ArrayList<Model>()
                data_.add(Model(department[p2]))
                val gson: Gson =Gson()
                val json:String = gson.toJson(data_)
                val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putString("list",json)
                editor.apply()
            }
```

**Fill adapter**

```
    val gson: Gson =Gson()
    val json: String? = sharedPreferences.getString("list",null)
    val type= object :TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>(){
    }.type
    data_ = gson.fromJson(json,type)
    if (data_ == null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else{
        val rec = binding.recyclerView
        rec.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val adapter = AddEditTextAdapter(data_)
        rec.adapter = adapter
    }
```

Comment: This will helps you https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-spinner-example-to-load-json-using-volley/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always re-initializing the `data_` array in the `onItemSelectedListener` function everytime.
You could declare separate functions to retrieve and set your `SharedPreference`:

```
fun getData(): ArrayList<Model>? {
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString("list", "")
    if (json == "") return null
    val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>(){ }.type
    return Gson().fromJson(json, type)
}

fun setData(data: ArrayList<Model>) {
    val json = Gson().toJson(data)
    sharedPreferences.edit()
        .putString("list", json)
        .apply()
}
```

And use these functions in your code:

```
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        val data_ = getData() ?: arrayListOf<Model>()
        // Add data to existing values
        data_.add(Model(department[p2]))
        // Update prefs
        setData(data_)
    }
}
```

New adapter's code:

```
val data_ = getData()
if (data_ == null){
    Toast.makeText(this,"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
else {
    val rec = binding.recyclerView
    rec.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val adapter = AddEditTextAdapter(data_)
    rec.adapter = adapter
}
```

Comment: It helps me. But how do i stop getting duplicate value

Comment: You should check if a `Model` is already present before calling the `.add` method

Comment: I used data.contains thanks..